# Laravel - Radio button in Bootstrap Datatable (yajra)

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, datatables

this is my scenario:
I'm using radio button in column in bootstrap datatable including a partial view in another, the partial contains this code:

```
<input type="radio" name="shipping_address_id" 
       value="{{$shippingAddress->id}}" {!! $shippingAddress->default?'checked="checked"':''!!} />
```

And it is added using datatable remote loading in this way:

```
 Datatables::of($addresses)
                    ->addColumn('action', function ($shippingAddress) {
                        return view('admin.shippingaddress.partials.actions_invoice', compact('shippingAddress'))->render();
                    })->make(true);
```

And it is rendered like this when $shippingAddress->default is false:

```
<input type="radio" name="shipping_address_id" value="8">
```

And like this when it is true:

```
<input type="radio" name="shipping_address_id" value="3" checked="checked" />
```

But when i call dt.reload()the rdb, even if it contains checked="checked" it is not really checked.

**Update**

Even when I initialize the datatable in this way:

```
addressesDataTable = $('#addressesDataTable').DataTable({
                processing: true,
                serverSide: true,
                searchDelay: 1000,
                ajax: {
                    type: 'GET',
                    url: url.replace('idToReplace', $('#buyerSelect').val()),
                    error: function (a, b, c) {
                        console.log(a);
                        console.log(b);
                        console.log(c);
                    },
                    dataSrc: function (response) {
                        return response.data;
                    }
                },
                columns: [
                    {data: 'name', name: 'countries.name'},
                    {data: 'postal', name: 'shipping_addresses.postal'},
                    {data: 'city', name: 'shipping_address.city'},
                    {data: 'address', name: 'shipping_address.address'},
                    {data: 'default', name: 'shipping_address.default'},
                    {data: 'action', name: 'action', orderable: false, searchable: false}
                ]
            });
```

Even when I reload the table (I tried using reload callback function in this way):

```
addressesDataTable.ajax.reload(function(){
                $('input[name=shipping_address_id]:checked').prop("checked", true);
            });
```

Checked radio button isn't really checked.

Comment: Where and how are you doing that `dt.reload()` call? Sounds like you are doing it in client side javascript. If that's the case, shouldn't you be passing a callback to take care of updating the already served html? Laravel takes care of the initial render, it has no concept of the functions you run in client-side javascript.

Comment: @JohnnyMagrippis I updated the question adding details

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: What do you mean by "it is not really checked"? The attribute is set but doesn't appear the checked mark? Or you see it checked but JS returns false?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have a radio button array and

```
                $('input[name=shipping_address_id]').prop("checked", true);
```

is checking all of them. When you have multiple radio buttons with same name, with all of them checked, the last checked one is shown as checked while others are not. You may have to filter to find the checkbox with the right id and then check it perhaps.

Comment: I updated the question and fixed my code adding ':checked'

Answer (score 0):

This problem is this line:

```
$("input[name=shipping_address_id]").prop("checked", true);
```

You are referencing **all** of the inputs with the name of `shipping_address_id` therefor you are also checking **all** of the inputs with the name of `shipping_address_id`.

If you only want to check **one** of the inputs then you could reference that input using its (unique) id / class.

If the input has a id then use:

```
$("input#id-of-your-input").prop("checked", true);
```

If the input has a class then use:

```
$("input.class-of-your-input").prop("checked", true);
```

> **NOTE:** If another element has the same className as that input then that element will also get checked.

Good luck and all the best.